# Visual Studio 2012 InstallShield LE .NET Framework 4.5 Prerequisites

Tags: .net, installshield, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, prerequisites

We have an application that was built using Visual Studio 2010 targeting the .NET Framework 4.0. We are upgrading the application to use .NET Framework 4.5 and is being written with Visual Studio 2012. Microsoft no longer provides a setup project type of their own, so we are forced to use this InstallShield LE. However, there appears to be a glaring omission in InstallShield's Prerequisites section. There is no option to declare that .NET Framework 4.5 must be installed, only .NET Framework 4.0 options. I've spent days trying to location the information to resolve this issue to no resolve. Flexera Software seems virtually unapproachable also as I can't seem to get a hold of anyone from that company to assist. It's not instilling me with much confidence in their product. How do I get .NET Framework 4.5 to be a prerequisite?

Comment: Just a follow up that we solved the issue by avoiding it altogether and decided to use InstallAware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). It has full support for .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8.

You can also try searching for a different setup authoring tool which supports .NET Framework 4.5 or at least allows you to create your own custom prerequisites. Here is a list which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Answer (score 2):

InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio hasn't been updated for the release of Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5 yet. The pending update will include new prerequisites for the new redistributables you mention that were made available with Visual Studio 2012.

The Professional and Premier editions of InstallShield also come with a prerequisite editor that allows the creation of prerequisites for new redistributables without having to wait for, e.g., Flexera Software to release them.

Comment: The InstallShield 2012 Spring Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012 is now available.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the PRQs directly from flexera at the following urls:

http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.5%20Web.prq
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.5.1%20Web.prq
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.5.2%20Web.prq
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.6%20Web.prq
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.6.1%20Web.prq
http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.7%20Web.prq

Strangely, they're not all available. 4.6.2 is missing, for instance. Some of the links above you can replace "Web" with "Full" as well.

Charles.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm trying to figure out what is best option for me  (Wix vs. Installshield LE)  I came across this question and I use VS 2012 ultimate and I see the 4.5 option....

[image]

Comment: Hey Chris, I know it was one year ago, but do you know how you got .Net 4.5? I don't seem to be able to see it in Installshield 2013 !!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps:
1>Create a prerequisite file for .net framework and please write the following as contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
  <conditions>
    <condition Type="2" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" FileName="Release" ReturnValue="378389"></condition>
  </conditions>
  <operatingsystemconditions>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
  </operatingsystemconditions>
  <files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\4.5\Full\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" URL="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255995" CheckSum="D02DC8B69A702A47C083278938C4D2F1" FileSize="0,50352408"></file>
  </files>
  <execute file="dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" cmdline="/showrmui /passive " cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1"></execute>
  <properties Id="{72D7E3D1-C9DF-4FA6-9F9B-4E5117AB2919}" Description="This prerequisite installs the .NET Framework 4.5 full standalone package." AltPrqURL="http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft .net framework 4.5 full.prq"></properties>
  <behavior Reboot="2"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```

Name the file as Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full.prq and copy it in [Installshield Installation folder\SetupPrerequisites] nad then you can see this prerequisite in Installation Requirements section in project Assistant

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps: 
1>Create a prerequisite file for .net framework and please write the following as contents:
Name the file as Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full.prq and copy it in [Installshield Installation folder\SetupPrerequisites] and then you can see this prerequisite in Redistributable  section in Application and Data part when you open Installshield2013 project in Visual studio and select it from redistriutable list and install it.

Content is below mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SetupPrereq>
  <conditions>
    <condition Type="2" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" FileName="Release" ReturnValue="378389"></condition>
  </conditions>
  <operatingsystemconditions>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4" ProductType="2|3"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="1" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="2" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="6" MinorVersion="3" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="1"></operatingsystemcondition>
    <operatingsystemcondition MajorVersion="10" MinorVersion="0" PlatformId="2" CSDVersion="" Bits="4"></operatingsystemcondition>
  </operatingsystemconditions>
  <files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\4.5\Full\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" URL="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255995" CheckSum="D02DC8B69A702A47C083278938C4D2F1" FileSize="0,50352408"></file>
  </files>
  <execute file="dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" cmdline="/showrmui /passive " cmdlinesilent="/q /norestart" returncodetoreboot="1641,3010" requiresmsiengine="1"></execute>
  <properties Id="{72D7E3D1-C9DF-4FA6-9F9B-4E5117AB2919}" Description="This prerequisite installs the .NET Framework 4.5 full standalone package." AltPrqURL="http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/microsoft .net framework 4.5 full.prq"></properties>
  <behavior Reboot="2"></behavior>
</SetupPrereq>
```